# open multiple .nc then write multiple raster

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster

I am a new programmer.  Recently I was given 1,850 .nc files which I subsetted to 480 files.  Each filename has a number to indicate the month.  All I want to do is:

1. open all .nc files
2. write all .nc files to raster format
3. average all raster files in 12 files, one for each month.

I know this shouldn't be difficult but I am having trouble.  So far I haven't gotten past step 2:

```
library(RNetCDF)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

files=list.files(pattern='*.nc', full.names=TRUE)

for (i in seq_along(files)){
 nc=open.nc(files[i])}

list(nc) 

for(i in 1:length(nc)){
  rnc<-raster(nc[i])
  writeRaster(rnc, filename=names(rnc), bylayer=TRUE, format="GTiff")}
```

As you all can tell, I am still a newbie/student of R, I think I have step 1 OK, the for loop for step 2 does not seem to be working.  Once I get 1 and 2 completed, I can work on 3 (if you all can see an easy answer for step 3 please share).

Thank you.

Comment: Your end goal is to calculate monthly mean right? Will it be better/faster to use either `RNetCDF` or `ncdf4` packages to read all grid point values ([example here](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/tag/oisst/)), calculate the mean then extract to tables with lat, long & mean values. After that it's fairly simple to create raster grids from the generated tables.

Comment: yes, all i want is to calculate monthly averages across all 480 files.  i looked at your script, but unfortunately, i had a hard time following it.  is there a simple way to do this using for loops for opening .nc and then either a for loop for estimating a mean based on the filename (e.g. skip step 2 and go to step 3), or a for loop for writing to a raster and then averaging?

Comment: They're not mine. [This one](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/03/extracting-sea-surface-temperatures-from-noaas-oisstv2/) is a little bit easier to follow. I'd try to start from there

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
files <- list.files(pattern='*.nc', full.names=TRUE)
```

Either:

```
s <- stack(files)
rnc <- writeRaster(s, filename="x", bylayer=TRUE, format="GTiff")}
```

Or with a loop:

```
for (f in files) {
    r <- raster(f)
    fout <- extension(f, '.tif')
    r <- writeRaster(r, filename=fout, datatype='FLT4S')
}
```

To get monthly averages, you can do something like:

```
months <- stackApply(s, 1:12, mean)
```

Assuming that the files are in the right order.